# Can I take a bicycle on the Windsor/Detroit truck ferry?

Tags: usa, canada, borders, bicycles, detroit

Neither the bridge nor the tunnel connecting Windsor (Ontario, Canada) to Detroit (Michigan, USA) allows bicycles.  According to Google Maps, the nearest ferry is on the other side of Lake St. Clair.

However, there appears to be a [truck ferry](http://www.truckferry.com). Although marketed for trucks, is it possible to use it as a cyclist, either formally or informally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Officially the answer is no. The Truck Ferry doesn't quote any tolls for cyclists or pedestrians. Unofficially the answer is likely to be no either, as using this ferry doesn't appear to be a known method to cyclists on either side of the border.

Your current options are:

- The [Tunnel Bus](http://www.citywindsor.ca/residents/transitwindsor/routes-and-schedules/tunnel-bus-to-detroit/pages/tunnel-bus-to-detroit.aspx), which requires the bike be disassembled and in a bike bag, and the bus not be full.
- A very long detour to the [Bluewater Ferry](http://www.bluewaterferry.com/) between Marine City and Sombra.
- [Bike the Bridge](http://www.tour-de-troit.org/bikethebridge), an annual event in which cyclists can cross the Ambassador Bridge. This is probably not a realistic option for travel.

The [New International Trade Crossing](http://buildthedricnow.com/) bridge, expected to open as early as 2020, [is planned to include a bike path](http://www.mlive.com/news/detroit/index.ssf/2013/03/bike_path_between_detroit_and.html). [A passenger ferry service](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/windsor/detroit-bankruptcy-won-t-scuttle-international-ferry-plans-1.1391327) which will permit cyclists is also planned.

Comment: Hmm.  [This fellow](http://www.crazyguyonabike.com/doc/page/?page_id=46969) seems to have succeeded.  Or maybe I qualify as hazardous material if I carry some camping fuel ;-).

Comment: @gerrit Yes, you can do that too. Just go have a long career working in CBSA and get to know the owner of the ferry... I suspect that will take longer than any of the other options.

Comment: Additionally, might a taxi, or combination of two taxis, be an option?

Comment: If you can get a taxi to take your bicycle, then by all means!

Comment: Note that [the Bluewater Ferry ceased operations in 2018.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sombra–Marine_City_(Bluewater)_Ferry)

Comment: Also, the new Detroit-Windsor bridge is now called the [Gordie Howe International Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordie_Howe_International_Bridge) and is expected to be completed in 2024.

Comment: How disassembled does the bike have to be for the Tunnel bus? If you remove the front wheel, and wrap the whole thing in a plastic bag, that might work. My guess is that you will be OK if the resulting parts will fit in the bus storage lockers.

Comment: This answer could do with an update (not so much concerning the Truck Ferry, but concerning the "current options" and the expected future)